# Will Select Max(field) under transaction lock any rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

We have this code and I am wondering, under normal Ado.net transaction will it actually lock any rows? Sample:

```
var sql1 = "SELECT MAX(entryNum) FROM tbl1 WHERE processNum = 1";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn, tran);
var newEntryNum = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
. . . . . . 
var sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl2 (entryNum) VALUES (" + newEntryNum  + ")";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn, tran);
```

In the first `select`, will it lock records with `processNum = 1`? To me, it looks like nothing will be locked. Is there a good reason to execute `SELECT MAX` under transaction the way its done?

Comment: 2 different programming languages and 2 different database servers? Make your mind up... With over 6k rep you should know better by now.

Comment: @DavidG I posted more understandable code. We have objects that abstract actual command, reader, etc. And we do use both, vb and c# . I don't want vb guys to shy away if they know the answer

Comment: Why is this question too broad? It is concrete question - lock or no lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *locking a row*, I assume you mean to prevent another transaction from modifying the row? I mention this because databases place all kinds of locks at different times that result in different locking behaviors.

In any case, the answer to your question has nothing to do with the programming language or ADO.NET.  It is entirely dependent on the database and isolation level used for your transaction.

For instance, in SQL Server, if you're running in `read committed` mode (which is the usual I would say), once the `select` query completes, it will not prevent another transaction from modifying the rows with `processNum = 1`.

However, if you are in `repeatable read` or `serializable` mode, then yes, executing the `select` query will place locks on the rows with `processNum = 1` that will prevent other transactions from modifying the rows until you complete your transaction.

You can read more about how SQL Server places locks for different isolation levels here: [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

In a previous edit of your question, you were also wondering about how this is handled in an Oracle database. That one is easy: no matter which isolation level you use, readers *never* block writers, so the `select` query would never prevent other transactions from modifying the rows.

Comment: Yes, you're right that I posted this to wider audience than desirable. I just went and tested this myself. What I've got with SqlServer is that `RepeatableRead` locks subset of rows  - `rocessNum = 1`. While  `Serializable` locks the whole table. And if no isolation is added, all rows are unlocked and you can even truncate the table. So this answers my bigger question - you do gain something from locking `SELECT MAX` but only if you pick appropriate `IsolationLevel`, in this case - `RepeatableRead`